# 500 : Internal Server Error The error was: nbconvert failed: clean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'css_sanitizer'

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

The common answer I am getting throughout the internet is to upgrade the nbconvert and I did it, but it is still not working!

```
pip install --upgrade nbconvert
```

What can possibly go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, nbconvert was using bleach 4.1.0, upgrading to 6.1.0 resolved the issue for me,

`pip install --upgrade bleach`